# Getting An Arbitrary Type From Reduce

Tags: swift, algorithm, mapkit, reduce

I'm doing a very simple operation. I'm sorting through a bunch of locations in a map to create an enclosing circle, like so:

```
var maxLong: Double = -180
var maxLat: Double = -180
var minLong: Double = 180
var minLat: Double = 180

for coord in inCoordinates {
    maxLong = max(coord.longitude, maxLong)
    maxLat = max(coord.latitude, maxLat)
    minLong = min(coord.longitude, minLong)
    minLat = min(coord.latitude, minLat)
}

let nw: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: maxLat, longitude: minLong)
let se: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: minLat, longitude: maxLong)
let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (maxLat + minLat) / 2.0, longitude: (maxLong + minLong) / 2.0)
let radiusInMeters = abs(nw.distance(from: se)) / 2.0

return MKCircle(center: center, radius: radiusInMeters)
```

Pretty straightforward (Yeah, I know about the IDL issue, but I want to keep this simple).

What I'd like to know, is if there were some way I could boil the loop into a variant of reduce, where you would end up with something like this:

```
let enclosingRect: MKMapRect = inCoordinates.magikalReduce {
    // Magic Happens Here -Queue Doug Henning GIF
}
```

So the returned rect contains the distilled points.

Yeah, I know that I can simply extend Array (with maybe a type qualifier) to do this with a calculated property, but that sort of defeats the purpose of this. The above is fairly efficient, and I'd rather not add overhead, just to be fancy (Which means, even if I could do it, it might be too inefficient to use).

This is more of a curiosity exploration than a technical need. The above code does fine for me, and is relatively zippy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean

```
// calculate the enclosing rect with `reduce` and `union`, you have to create an `MKMapRect` from each coordinate
let enclosingRect = inCoordinates.reduce(MKMapRect.null) { $0.union(MKMapRect(origin: MKMapPoint($1), size: MKMapSize())) }
```

Comment: Or `inCoordinates.reduce(MKMapRect.null) { $0.union(MKMapRect(origin: MKMapPoint($1), size: MKMapSize())) }` without an intermediate array.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `struct` for holding the min/max longitude and latitude values, then use `reduce`, where you use the initial values for these for creating an initial result, then creating an updated version of the `struct` with the necessary `min`/`max` calculations.

```
struct MinMaxCoordinates {
    let maxLong:Double
    let maxLat:Double
    let minLong:Double
    let minLat:Double
}


let minMaxCoordinates = inCoordinates.reduce(MinMaxCoordinates(maxLong: -180, maxLat: -180, minLong: 180, minLat: 180), {minMax, coord in
    return MinMaxCoordinates(maxLong: max(minMax.maxLong, coord.longitude), maxLat: max(minMax.maxLat, coord.latitude), minLong: min(minMax.minLong, coord.longitude), minLat: max(minMax.minLat, coord.latitude))
})

let nw: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: minMaxCoordinates.maxLat, longitude: minMaxCoordinates.minLong)
let se: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: minMaxCoordinates.minLat, longitude: minMaxCoordinates.maxLong)
let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (minMaxCoordinates.maxLat + minMaxCoordinates.minLat) / 2.0, longitude: (minMaxCoordinates.maxLong + minMaxCoordinates.minLong) / 2.0)
let radiusInMeters = abs(nw.distance(from: se)) / 2.0

return MKCircle(center: center, radius: radiusInMeters)
```